# PHP strict_types and relation to invisible TYPO3-record

Tags: typo3, extbase

A property of the model is a relation to **one** other record like this:

```
/**
 * @var \MyCompany\MyExtension\Domain\Model\OtherObject
 */
public $otherObject;

/**
 * @return OtherObject
 */
public function getOtherObject(): OtherObject
{
    return $this->otherObject;
}
```

Now, assume the connected object to be invisible (e.g. it's hidden or time-restricted). Extbase is trying to assign 0, but PHP expects an instance of OtherObject... Bam! - you get an error.

How to deal with that? Hidden or time-restricted records are not uncommon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to require PHP 7.1 and use a nullable return type hint like `?OtherObject` or remove the type hint completely for now. In any case you cannot rely on something being returned here so your consuming code needs to handle this.